# Should I skip the gym in middle when I can't take enough protein

Tags: muscle, strength, protein

I have been working out in gym for the last **3 months**.... [ **4 days** week , **30 minutes** per day ]

I want **muscle , shape** & want to be **fit**....

I did't see any major improvements as I **did't** workout out **intensively** & did't take **enough protein**. (maximum I was taking is 50 g protein from food per day (no other protein supplements) , but I need at least 120 g protein per day for my body weight.)

Also, due to another reason, I can't take more than 50 gm protein per day for the next month. After one month, I can take up to more than 120 g protein per day.

So, is it better to go and workout in gym for next month, or is it better to skip gym for next month? Is there any advantage in going to the gym for next month ?

Comment: please leave a comment for downvote,so that it will help to improve me....

Comment: You are taking 50 g Protein from whey only or total? Believe it or not, there is protein in food, too. Also, what have you based the 120 g on? There are recommendations up to nearly 2 g per kg bodyweight, which rather seems to be the **upper limit**, but you'll make *some* progress with 1 g per kg bodyweight, too.

Comment: @PaulK i am not taking any `whey` , i am taking 50 g protein from foods.... as i weigh 68 kgs , is taking 68g protein per day is enough ?

Comment: My bad, I thought you would since I associated "taking protein" with supplements (as opposed to "ingesting protein" and the like).

Comment: @PaulK that's fine....  it was my mistake that i did't mentioned clearly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a great article of *Bayesian Bodybuilding* ([see here](https://bayesianbodybuilding.com/the-myth-of-1glb-optimal-protein-intake-for-bodybuilders/)) conferring the results of various studies. They are stating that

> [...] 1.8g/kg (0.82g/lb) is the point at which additional protein intake ceases to yield any benefits.

and

> no differences in whole body protein synthesis or indexes of lean body mass in strength athletes consuming either 0.64g/lb or 1.10g/lb over a 2 week period

and

> The authors suggested that 0.55g/lb was sufficient for bodybuilders.

Following that data, your optimal protein intake would be something between 80 g and 100 g, **but** this does not mean that you should skip the gym altogether. On the one hand there will still be neural adaption (depending on the weight/reps) and on the other hand there is still an effect on protein synthesis if you are at 1 g per kg bodyweight (there is a ugly but very informative graphic at the end of the *Studies on the optimal protein intake* section of the article).

Comment: thanks, i will go to gym & try to do something for those proteins....